# Electric field at some distance(a) from charged particles arranged in a straight line?

Tags: electric-fields, charge

I know that there are derivations of charged infinite wire and we can get the total electric field by integrating over the whole wire.

but if now we imagine that the wire is not continuous instead there are charges at equal distance(a) from each other and the observation point is (a) distance away (at the middle of the wire) from the wire then what would be the generalized equation for the electric field experienced because of the all charged particles arranged in the line for '2n' elements('n' and 'n' on both sides).

Comment: Where you got stuck?

Comment: Have you considered changing the limits of the integral?